# Show search bar when scrolled down and hide it when scrolled back to top

Tags: jquery

I need to show a sticky search bar at the top when the page is scrolled down. The landing page already contains a search box. So, the sticky bar should come only when it's out of view, and when the search box comes back in to view, the sticky search bar should go off. How do I do this using jquery?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/ also note you are unlikely to get much help unless you show that you have at least attempted doing some code or showing more research.

Comment: Thanks Stemie. And sorry for not adding my code or more details. This is my first time here.

Answer (score 1):

As stemie said, you will get much more answers if it looks like you gave it a shot but here it is anyway. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/904v75t5/1/) for full example. Next time give it a try and post relevant code

jQuery

```
var searchHeight = $(".search-bar").outerHeight();
var offset = $(".search-bar").offset().top;
var totalHeight = searchHeight + offset;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= totalHeight) {
        $('.sticky-search').show();
    } else {
         $('.sticky-search').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zach. And sorry for not adding my code or more details. This is my first time here.